# How can I check if two cyclic sequences that are stored in arrays are equal (Java)?

Tags: java, arrays, indexing, sequence, cyclic

For my class, I have been tasked with writing a program in Java that tells you whether 2 DNA sequences each of length 8, stored in an array, are the same. However, the sequences can be cyclic. For example, these two are the same:

A T G C G T A T

A T A T G C G T

I have written the code that checks if both arrays at index 0 are the same, and if they are, it goes to a check array method, while if they are not, it adds 1 to the index of the second array and starts again. However, I am pretty stumped as I am not sure how I can input the new index at which the check method go through the two arrays, or how to loop the indexes (i.e. from 7 back to 0).

Sorry if the code is rubbish, but I am a beginner and have found this question very confusing.
Thanks in advance :)

```
/* checking whether the two arrays are equal at a certain index

for (x=0;x<8;) {
            for (y=0;y<8;) {
                if (DNAarray1[x] == DNAarray2[y]) {
                    isEqual(ADNarray1, ADNarray2);
                } else y++;
            }
        }

/* isEqual method - my issue is with how I can take x and y from above and carry them into this method.
And also how to loop this back round so the index of y goes from 7 back to 0.

static boolean isEqual(int[] ADN1, int[] ADN2) {
        for (int c = 1; c < 8; c++) {
            if (ADN1[x + c] == ADN2[y + c]) {
                return true;
            } else return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To get x and y into the method just add parameters of same name
To go back to 0 after 7 use the modulo operator %.

Here is you code with the necessary changes and some fixes:

```
static boolean isCyclicEqual(int[] DNA1, int[] DNA2) {
    for (x=0;x<8;x++) {
        for (y=0;y<8;y++) {
            if (isEqual(DNAarray1, x, DNAarray2, y)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

static boolean isEqual(int[] DNA1, int x, int[] DNA2, int y) {
    for (int c = 0; c < 8; c++) {
        if (DNA1[(x + c) % 8] != DNA2[(y + c) % 8]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you have only `8` elements in the arrays, then performance is not critical for the solution. Then it could be like this:

```java
public static boolean isEqualCycle(char[] one, char[] two) {
    String strOne = new String(one);
    String strTwo = new String(two);

    for (int i = 0; i < one.length; i++) {
        if (strOne.equalsIgnoreCase(strTwo))
            return true;
        strTwo = strTwo.charAt(strTwo.length() - 1) + strTwo.substring(0, strTwo.length() - 1);
    }

    return false;
}
```

---

Another soulion is to use additional array:

```java
public static boolean isEqualCycle(char[] one, char[] two) {
    char[] tmp = Arrays.copyOf(two, two.length);

    for (int i = 0; i < one.length - 1; i++) {
        if (isEqual(one, tmp))
            return true;
        rotateRight(tmp);
    }

    return false;
}

private static boolean isEqual(char[] one, char[] tmp) {
    for (int i = 0; i < one.length; i++)
        if (one[i] != tmp[i])
            return false;
    return true;
}

private static void rotateRight(char[] arr) {
    for (int i = 0, j = arr.length - 1; i < j; i++, j--)
        swap(arr, i, j);
    for (int i = 1, j = arr.length - 1; i < j; i++, j--)
        swap(arr, i, j);
}

private static void swap(char[] arr, int i, int j) {
    char tmp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[j];
    arr[j] = tmp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the DNA sequences are represented as strings / string arrays, it may be convenient to use [`Collections.rotate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#rotate-java.util.List-int-) method to perform cyclic shift:

```java
static boolean isEqual(String[] one, String[] two) {
    if (one.length != two.length) return false; // verify the length
    
    List<String> sec = Arrays.asList(two);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < one.length; i++) {
        if (Arrays.equals(one, two)) {
            System.out.println("equal at position=" + i);
            return true;
        }
        Collections.rotate(sec, -1); // contents of `two` is rotated as well
    }
    System.out.println("non-equal");
    return false;
}
```

Test:

```
isEqual("ATGCGTAT".split(""), "ATATGCGT".split(""));
isEqual("ATGCGTAT".split(""), "TATGGCTA".split(""));
```

Output:

```
equal at position=2
non-equal
```